# What the difference between xs:decimal and number in xslt 2

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

What the difference between `xs:decimal` and `number` in xslt 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT and XPath 1.0 there was just a single number type, double precision floating point numbers. XSLT and XPath 2.0 has a richer type system taken from the W3C XML schema language (and partly extending that type system).

`xs:decimal` is both a type and a [constructor function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#constructor-functions) in XSLT and XPath 2.0 so you can use it where you specify a sequence type, like in the `as` attribute (e.g. `<xsl:param name="input" as="xs:decimal"/>`) as well as to convert a value to an `xs:decimal` value in any XPath expression e.g. `<xsl:variable name="input" select="xs:decimal(//foo)"/>`.

The `[number][2]` function exists since XSLT and XPath 1.0 and converts its argument to a double precision floating point number, represented in the XSLT and XPath 2.0 type system by the type `xs:double` e.g. `<xsl:variable name="input" select="number(//foo)"/>`. There is also a [constructor function `xs:double`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#constructor-functions) in XPath and XSLT 2.0.